# Google Calendar Events integeration with Rails app

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using **google_apis_calendar_v3** for my Rails application integration with google calendar. I have implemented and tested push notifications for calendar's incremental events syncing. Push notification for Google Calendar events changes are working fine on local_production but push notifications are not working on live server.

I have followed t[his guide](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) and also verify my app from Google Search console.

In account.rb:

```
def make_watch_event_channel
    status = self.authorize_google_calendar_service
    return if status != 200

    callback_url = "#{APP_URL}/calendars/my_event_changes?my_account_id=#{self.id}"
    time_min = DateTime.now.rfc3339
    channel_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10, false)

    begin
      @channel = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Channel.new(address: callback_url, id: channel_id, type: "web_hook")
      @webhook = @service.watch_event('primary', @channel, single_events: true, time_min: time_min)
      self.calendars&.last&.update(resource_id: @webhook.resource_id, channel_id: channel_id)
    rescue Google::Apis::AuthorizationError, Google::Apis::ClientError, Signet::AuthorizationError => e
      Rails.logger.info "-------------------------"
      Rails.logger.info e.message
      Rails.logger.info "-------------------------"
    end
end
```

Comment: Code has been added, so voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It was actually nginx configuration issue
Inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf, I was redirecting 'https://www.example.com' to 'https://example.com'. So I gave callback_url 'https://example.com' inseatd of 'https://www.example.com'.